# Weird line of c# code that works

Tags: c#

```
return Json(new { ErrorMessage = scheduleBase.ErrorMessage }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); ;
```

Is this just a weird case of me not being able to correctly see what the other semi-colon relates to? This code compiles and actually works fine, but I'm stumped as to why.

I found it in a co-workers code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are c# allow double semicolon ; ; if yes then are their any special ways](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790771/are-c-allow-double-semicolon-if-yes-then-are-their-any-special-ways)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The extra semicolon is an empty statement after the `return ...;`.
It is useless and harmless.

Empty statements are useful as loop bodies:

```
while (str[++i] != '#')
    ;
```

---

They're also a common source of bugs:

```
if (something) ; 
{
    ...
}
```

This block is not connected to the `if` statement; the condition only applies to the empty statement.
The C# compiler will give a warning here.

Comment: I had no idea you could have empty statements like that.

Comment: @Slaks - that was my next question actually. How are they ever useful? Could you explain how that is useful in that loop body?

Comment: @slandau: You need _something_ as the loop body, but there's nothing to put in it here.  You could also write `{}`.

Comment: Why would you loop through something if in each iteration you are performing nothing, not even counting?

Comment: @slandau: `++i`.  Don't write real code like this.  A more "real" example would be `while (!CheckReady()) ;`, although there are better ways to do that (`ManualResetEvent`)

Comment: +1 for the source of bugs. For one company I used to work for, during the interview the gave us a bunch of broken code to debug. This was one of the issues.

Answer (score 4):

Extra semicolons aren't errors.

Comment: I like to use 3 semicolons after my statements just for good measure.

Comment: it's just common sense - the compiler may optimize it away if you only use one ;)